# How to install apt back after apt-transport-https uninstalled it

Tags: debian, apt

I followed a suggestion and bricked my server. I no longer have `apt` / `apt-get` after installing `apt-transport-https` and I regret it.

I tried installing apt via `dpkg` but it errors out with:

```
dpkg: regarding apt_1.8.2.1_amd64.deb containing apt:
 apt breaks apt-transport-https (<< 1.5~alpha4~)
  apt-transport-https (version 1.4.10) is present and installed.

dpkg: error processing archive apt_1.8.2.1_amd64.deb (--install):
 installing apt would break apt-transport-https, and
 deconfiguration is not permitted (--auto-deconfigure might help)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apt_1.8.2.1_amd64.deb
```

how do I uninstall `apt-transport-https` and revert back?

Comment: It's debian 10 .

Comment: apt-transport-https isn't supposed to be installed on Debian 10+. the apt/apt-get packages had native support for the https transport. If you tried to force the installation of older/newer version you probably have seriously broken something, at that point, it almost be easier to just format+reinstall.

Comment: format+reinstall will bring a big downtime to my server. Did I really broke it so bad that it's unrecoverable?

Comment: how do you remove `apt-transport-https` when you have no `apt` which was removed by `apt-transport-https` :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of `apt-transport-https` you have installed came from Debian 9, and the version of `apt` you propose to install is from Debian 11. Neither is appropriate for your Debian 10 system. `apt-transport-https` was deprecated in Debian 10 as its functionality is now included directly in `apt`.

You both need to remove `apt-transport-https` and get the [correct version of `apt` for Debian 10](https://packages.debian.org/buster/apt).

---

You said that dpkg still works, so you should be able to use it to remove `apt-transport-https`. For example:

```
dpkg --purge apt-transport-https
```

After that you should be able to reinstall the correct `apt` package downloaded from debian.org as shown above.

```
dpkg --install apt_1.8.2.1_amd64.deb
```

Note that if you also deleted any of its dependencies, you will need to locate and install those first. An error message will tell you if this is necessary.